# Webpack2 keep adding dev dependancy file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I have this kind of configuration like below. However, it seems to load development script even though the if statement go into only "production"

```
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      module.exports = require('./configureStoreProd')
  } else {
      module.exports = require('./configureStoreDev')
  }
```

If I delete the *"import logger from 'redux-logoer"*, it does not show on analyzer.

I am guessing when webpack building vendor file, NODE_ENV is undefine or null. How do i set it properly ?

Comment: What is the command that you tested to build in production?

Comment: command is like this!  NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --config  webpack/config/config.com.js.

Comment: Have you tried building it using `npm run build` and then checking if it uses the _NODE_ENV === 'production'_ then?

Comment: It print out production in webpack.config file but not in other js files. I dont think you can console.log in other files while webpack running

Comment: Are `./configureStoreProd` and `./configureStoreDev` used only to configure your store at the start of your application?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: yes  petithomme  and tried define-plugin  already

Answer (score 0):

Workaround I used:

Your config file (that you will import in the js files you wish to use it in) that determines what file you will use depending on the environment you are in.

**config.js**

```
var config = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  config = require('./config.development');
}else {
  config = require('./config.production');
}

export default config;
```

Your config production **.json** file that will be selected if you are in the production environment. Same goes for development.

**config.production.json**

```
{
    "graphQlEndpoint": {
        "uri": "YourUriHere"
    },
}
```

In the store, you can import the config.js file and then choose what variable you want. Example: config -> graphQlEndpoint -> uri

**store.js**

```
import config from '../../configs/config';

networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: config.graphQlEndpoint.uri
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, networkInterface);
```

I found it easier to use `require()` and to have my **config** files in son. You can then use your config file with the correct environment everywhere you import it.

I suggest you test this with `npm run build`.

Hope this helps

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV  works if i run it. What I am trying to fix is removing dev related library from vendor. I feel webpack get all the import require without checking if statement

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the question. I also used `DefinePlugin` for that part. I think it's the best way to go.

Comment: In `web pack.config.prod.js`, there's a section with the comment: `Makes some environment variables available to the JS code` and you can define plugin below that.

Comment: where is it ? I am not using boilerplate code so i am not sure

Comment: @SeongjunKim Search for the file named `webpack.config.prod.js`. I use _Visual Studio Code_ so the command I'm using to search for a file is `Ctrl` + `e`.

Comment: If you have trouble finding it, I think it's in `node-modules` => `react-scripts` => `webpack.config.prod.js`